How to test external fetch API function with connectionerror exception Django
My code snippet fetches data from an external API. It works fine and I tested the results when I don't have any issues with the connection. However, I'm interested on testing my try except block that handles any connection problem during the function execution. I'm using python 'requests' library and I don't have any complain about it but I feel testing a connection issue will reassure my code does throw the exception.
This is the closest StackOverflow answer for python only, I couldn't implement it in my code though. Also, I found another answer that suggested using Httpretty but I don't that's the approach to this question.
Does anyone know how to simulate failures for external API data fetching?
views.py
def fetch_question(request):
    handler = APIHandler()

    match request.POST["difficulty"]:
        case "easy":
            url = (
                "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple&token="
                + handler.token
            )
        case "medium":
            url = (
                "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple&token="
                + handler.token
            )
        case "hard":
            url = (
                "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=9&difficulty=hard&type=multiple&token="
                + handler.token
            )


    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except ConnectionError: # Want to test this exception 
        response.raise_for_status()
    else:
        return render_question(request, response.json())

test_views.py
from django.test import TestCase, Client

client = Client()


class QuestionTest(TestCase):
    def test_page_load(self):
        response = self.client.get("/log/question")
        self.assertEqual(response["content-type"], "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "log/question.html")
        self.assertContains(response, "Choose your question level", status_code=200)

    def test_fetch_question(self): #Test for successful data fetch 
        response = self.client.post(
            "/log/question", {"level": "level", "difficulty": "hard"}, follow=True
        )
        self.assertEqual(len(response.context), 2)
        self.assertIn("question", response.context)
        self.assertIn("answers", response.context)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.context["answers"]), 4)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "log/question.html")

    # how to test connection error?


Limit your network connection speed from network adapter settings, then check with wireshark for the api request, disconnect your network adapter as soon as the request gets sent in network connections

Thanks @SubrataSarkar! Actually I'm looking for a way to do it inside the test.
